# Firebase data being returned multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the database in sort of a weird way.

Basically, what I am trying to do is,

1. retrieve all the db users
2. compare data of all user with that of the current users
3. if match - store that data in a node "Matches/"
4. then retrieve that data sorted. (sorted is important which is why im using forEach, because without it i can retrieve the data just fine.)

now the problem Im facing is that data gets retrieved, sorted, but it's getting retrieved multiple times (the number of matches * the number of matches times) which I suppose is happening because of the nested forEach loops. any suggestions on how to fix this?

Database schema :

[image]

Code:

```
// Go through all the users and get their names.
var rootRef2 = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
rootRef2.once("value", function (snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function (child) {

// Go to "Arrays/" and get all the "SStrings" 
var rootRef3 = firebase.database().ref().child("Arrays/" + child.key);
rootRef3.once("value", function (snapshot) {

  var datasnap = snapshot.val();
  var SString = datasnap.SString;
  var nambe = datasnap.name;

  //compare the current_user inputed strings (FinalSongString) with inputed strings of all other users (SString) 
  var DbMatch = [finalSongString, SString];

  //find how many values match
  var DbResult = DbMatch.shift().filter(function (v) {
    return DbMatch.every(function (a) {
      return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    });
  });

  //data formating from here **********
  var DBindexes = [];
  var DBresultArr = [];

  DbResult.forEach(function (source) {
    DBindexes.push(finalSongString.indexOf(source))
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < DBindexes.length; i++)
    DBresultArr.push(" " + userSongs[DBindexes[i]]);

  // only continue is there is a match with someone other than current_user
  if (DbResult.length >= 1 && child.key != username) {

    for (var i = 0; i < DBresultArr.length; i++) {
      DBresultArr[i] = DBresultArr[i].capitalize().replace(/ -/g, " -");
    }

  // to here **********

    // Create node "Matches/" in the database to store the data that matches
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Matches");
    var userMatches =
    {
      "the_matched": nambe,
      "matches": DBresultArr,
      "nr_of_matches": DBresultArr.length,
    };

    rootRef.child(db_name).child(child.key).set(userMatches, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
        window.alert("Message:" + errorMessage);
      }
      else {
        //nothing please, just do the if.
      }
    });

    //download the data that is under the Current_User ID (db_name) in the "Matches" node. ordered by number of matches.
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('Matches/' + db_name).orderByChild('nr_of_matches')
    ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
        const matches = child.val().matches
        const nr_of_matches = child.val().nr_of_matches
        const the_matched = child.val().the_matched
        console.log("matches : " + matches)

        document.getElementById("ppl").style.visibility = "visible";

        counter++;
        console.log(counter)

        if (nr_of_matches == 1) {
          document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML += " <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></br> <span class='counter'> #" + counter + "</span> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><span class='name'>" + the_matched + "</span>" +
            "<br>" + "<span class='common'> You have </span>" + "<span class='common'>" + nr_of_matches +
            "</span>" + "<span class='common'>song in common:</span><br><br><br> <span class='common2'>" +
            matches + "</span><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
        }
        else if (nr_of_matches >= 2) {
          document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML += " <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></br> <span class='counter'> #" + counter + "</span> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><span class='name'>" + the_matched + "</span>" +
            "<br>" + "<span class='common'> You have </span>" + "<span class='common'>" + nr_of_matches +
            "</span>" + "<span class='common'>songs in common:</span> <br><br><br> <span class='common2'>" +
            matches + "</span><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
        }
      });
    });
  }
})
});
});
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem :(

Comment: That was quite some time ago, and I don't remember exactly what I did to fix it, but you can see the entire page and see if it helps https://github.com/alberkko/results/blob/master/res.js